# Getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53 in Laravel 5.1 while using csrf token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
I am using `{!!Form::open()!!}`
`{!!Form::close!!}`. When I click the add Button in my form with empty field for the first time, it shows me error as I set the validation rule. But when I click the Add button again without refreshing the page, it shows me the TokenMismatchException error. I have checked with dd() and it shows me the token like this:

```
 array:3 [▼
 "_token" => "5dXwRHbz4GNY1tx9OVeWPcOkirVIm0YtpkZufFbr"
 "menu_name" => ""
 "menu_price" => ""
```

Here is my form code:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' =>'upcoming.store', 'method'=>'POST')) !!}
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-offset-3 top-spacing">
                        <input type="text" name="menu_name" placeholder="Menu Name.." class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-offset-3 top-spacing">
                        <input type="text" name="menu_price" placeholder="Menu Price.." class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8 top-spacing">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">
                            Add +
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is my controller store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'menu_name'=>'required',
        'menu_price'=>'required',
        ));
    $upcoming = new Upcomingfood;
    $upcoming->menu_name=$request->menu_name;
    $upcoming->menu_price=$request->menu_price;
    $upcoming->save();
    Session::flash('success','Food Menu Added Successfullly');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you replace the `redirect()->back()` with  `route('upcoming_food/create')` or `view('upcoming_food/create')` in your scenario? Made up the route name and the view name.

Comment: Also does adding `withInput()` changes anything? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects#creating-redirects

Comment: Still no solution :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by going to

```
`VerifyCsrfToken.php`
```

and then I have changed

`throw new TokenMismatchException;`
 by 
`else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }`

But I am not sure am I right or wrong to apply this way. will it bring any problem in my future work in this project. anyone please make me sure. please.

Answer (score -1):

Try add

```
 {{ csrf_field() }}
```

inside the form.

I really recommend that you read official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: Why I should use  `{{ csrf_field() }}` while I am using `Form::open and close` . and it is also printing the token with dd as I mentioned in my Question. By the way I tried with `{{ csrf_field() }}`. But it still gives me the same result. thanks.